# What's the term for linking two or more databases to one big database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle

What's the term for linking two or more databases to one big database ?
To explain more : i have an idea to make a program for a multi branch company. So the thing that i want to make for each branch a small database and all of these branches are linked directly to the mother branch where the big database is situated .
Any suggestions for terms to use in order to find what i want online and learn ?

Comment: I think you're finding something called Read Replicas, Slave DB nodes or Master DB nodes.

Comment: As you said, a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083) (that's Oracle 11g, but I think others do something similar.

c.f. "distributed database"

Comment: The question is clearly out of scope for Stack Overflow, which is for programming questions. Unfortunately it has already received three answers...

Comment: Just set separate schemas for each branch under the same instance, which should suffice. This way your linkage will be implemented through addressing the DBs via schema prefix.

Comment: ["database shard"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) may also be relevant.  But more than likely the most relevant term will become "over-engineered".  A single database is good enough most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking for Datawarehouse if you are dealing with BigData. If you would want to make Data marts and make some dashboards for the management it would come handy.

Answer (score 0):

If the databases have the same schema, you probably could use [SQL-Hub](http://sql-hub.com/Page/index.php?Shortname=Home).
At their website you can also find some information concerning the topic database-merging.